# Why are certain control properties shown in the Visual Studio designer, and others not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, designer, propertyeditor

Take my navigationItem usercontrol:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Uboldi.Helpers;

namespace Uboldi
{
    public partial class NavigationItem : UserControl
    {
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public NavigationItem()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RefreshDisplay();
        }

        private void RefreshDisplay()
        {
            if (IsSelected)
                this.BackColor = CustomizationHelper.GetSecondaryColor();
            else
                this.BackColor = CustomizationHelper.GetPrimaryColor();            
        }
    }
}
```

In Visual Studio I can see the IsSelected property, but not the Text property.
[image]

Any reason why?

Comment: The correct terminology is "Property" not attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The Text property is inherited from UserControl.  Where it is hidden, a user control has no meaningful way of of showing text.  You have to inherit it again and turn all the attributes off that make it hidden.  Like this:

```
    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public override string Text {
        get { return base.Text; }
        set { base.Text = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788818/changes-in-my-usercontrol-are-erased-when-i-rebuild-in-visual-studio-designer-vi

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the properties you want visible in the design time properties list with a [BrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx).

```
[Browsable(true)]
public bool Text { get; set; }
```

At a guess, the IsSelected property was inherited, and had this attribute set. I'm probably off, because I think the compiler would warn you that you were shadowing an inherited property if this was the case.

Comment: Why does it say: "Warning: You must rebuild your project for the changes to Uboldi.LeftNavigationbar to show up in any open designers." And when I rebuild, the change is lost?